# My condition in JS doesn't work in my function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a condition when my tabs "coms" doesn't have any coms, the website say :"you don't have any coms.

below my condition :

```
renderMesCommentaires = () => {
    return this.state.mesComs.commentaires.map((element, index) => {
      /* const statuts = element.texte.map((statut) => (
        <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: statut.texte }}></p>
      ));*/

      console.log(this.state.commentaires);
      const coms= this.state.commentaires
        if (coms === ''){
          return(
            <h4>Vous n'avez pas encore de commentaires</h4>
          )
        } else{
          return (
          <div className="divCom" key={index}>
            <div className="nomPrenom"><h2 className="prenomCom">{element.prenom}</h2> <h2 className="nomCom">{element.nom} </h2>
            
            </div>
           <div><p className="statut2">{element.texte}</p></div>
            </div>
        );}
      
    });
  };
```

Also my state

```
this.state = {
      mesComs: { commentaires: [] },
    };
  }
```

Comment: If your `coms` is array, then `coms === ''` will not work. `if (coms.length === 0)` maybe? Also - add framework tag to question, as it's not plain JS

Comment: You don't have `this.state.commentaires` state! this condition is always false!

Comment: btw don't use index as the key in react. It's an anti pattern. https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an array to an empty string:
`[]===''` is always `false`.

If you are trying to check if the array is empty then:
`[].length === 0` would work.

in your case:

```
if (coms,length === 0){
  return(
    <h4>Vous n'avez pas encore de commentaires</h4>
  )
} else {
  //...
}
```

Comment: Generally correct but I guess he shouldn't check it within the map function. Just put the condition before the map, if length exists then render the map, otherwise render your fallback, can you update your answer?

Comment: @JulianKleine I think there is a difference between `mesComs` and `coms` so the map is on `mesComs` not the latter.

Comment: possible :) i just added the other version, hope it helps, feel free to update your answer if it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
renderMesCommentaires = () => {
  return this.state.mesComs.commentaires.length > 0 ? (
    <h4>Vous n'avez pas encore de commentaires</h4>
  ) : (
    this.state.mesComs.commentaires.map((element, index) => {
      <div className="divCom" key={index}>
        <div className="nomPrenom">
          <h2 className="prenomCom">{element.prenom}</h2>{" "}
          <h2 className="nomCom">{element.nom} </h2>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p className="statut2">{element.texte}</p>
        </div>
      </div>;
    })
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code

```
return this.state.mesComs.commentaires.map((element, index) => {
   ...
})
```

will map over all the elements in your array and then execute the code within the brackets. When the array is empty, the code is not executed at all - so your `if` statement is not executed either.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you don't want to check it within your map function. Check it before mapping. Also don't check for strings, check for the length of the array

```js
const renderMesCommentaires = () => {
  if (!this.state.mesComs.commentaires.length) {
    return <h4>Vous n'avez pas encore de commentaires</h4>;
  }
  return this.state.mesComs.commentaires.map((element, index) => (
    <div className="divCom" key={index}>
      <div className="nomPrenom">
        <h2 className="prenomCom">{element.prenom}</h2>{" "}
        <h2 className="nomCom">{element.nom} </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p className="statut2">{element.texte}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};
```